# Decreasing a timer over time in Adobe Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So basically my ball moves to a random location on the screen once it hears the (3000) tick. How can I make the timer slowly decrease so that the ball moves faster and faster over time?

```
var timmyTimer:Timer = new Timer(3000)

timmyTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tick)
timmyTimer.start();

function tick(t:TimerEvent):void {
mcBall.x = Math.floor(Math.random() *(stage.stageWidth - mcBall.width));
mcBall.y = Math.floor(Math.random() *(stage.stageHeight - mcBall.height));
mcBall.nextFrame();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your question now, 3000 milliseconds is your `Timer` object's [`delay`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html#delay), so to decrease that value, you can, for example, write :

```
function tick(t:TimerEvent):void 
{
    t.target.delay -= 100;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Just put it into my code and it worked perfectly, thanks SO much!

Comment: sorry, one last issue. The game now crashes because it tries to beyond 0. how can i stop this? sorry!

Comment: @Jarrod No problem. You can use, for example, an `if` statement like this :  : `if(t.delay > 100){ t.delay -= 100; }` ...